# Datepicker in an entire column using PHPExcel

Tags: php, datepicker, phpexcel

I have managed to create a dropmenu in my excel file, which I am generating using the following code.

Could you please tell me how to add datepicker in an entire column using PHPExcel? I have looked for possible solutions in http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ but haven't found any.

```
$column = 'I';
$lastRow = 1000;
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) 
{           
        $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$row)->getDataValidation();
        $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
        $objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
        $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
        $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
        $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
        $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
        $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
        $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
        $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
        $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
        $objValidation->setFormula1('"M,F"');
}
```

Comment: There is no method to apply validation to a range of cells, it needs to be applied to each individually

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that. But could you please show me how to add a datepicker in one cell atleast ?